# AWS SAM : Nested Stacks, Referring to API gateway from the Root stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-sam

I want to split my SAM application into multiple parts.

I want to create a API ( AWS::Serverless::Api ) in the root stack.

I am creating lambda functions in my child stacks, where I want to give the reference of the API from the root stack to the API Events.

Is this feasible?  I didn't find any good examples for the accessing the API from the root stack into child stack?

I tried with the below template -

```
parenttemplateapi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Location:
        ApplicationId: arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:account_id:applications/parent-template
        SemanticVersion: 1.0.0



HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Method: get
            Path: /hello
            RestApiId: !GetAtt parenttemplateapi.Outputs.ServerlessGW-restApiId
```

When I tried to deploy this template, I got below errors -

> Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: child-template, ex:
>   Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal
>   failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Transform
>   AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Internal transform failure.

Any pointers/suggestions?

I was referring to below links -

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-nested-applications-for-aws-sam-and-the-aws-serverless-application-repository/

Can the API Gateway Id ( AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi) from the root stack used here?

https://dev.to/grahamcox82/building-a-larger-serverless-application-part-3-modular-monorepos-3mon

**Can this be achieved using serverless framework?**

Comment: Did you find a solution in another place?

Comment: This should be possible. However, I would like to know how the parent template looks like and if it contains an output which is named ServerlessGW-restApiId.

Comment: @MartinLöper I wonder if you and I worked together on a Visa Token Service Wallet Application once! :) If so, nice bumping into you out here in the Digital Wild West!

Comment: @lopezdp Not that I remember. But nice to meet you anyway here in the Digital Wild West :D

Comment: Did you find a solution? by using SAM, not serverless framework?

Answer (score 3):

The caveat here is that I do not use AWS SAM as I only use `serverless.yml` ServerlessFramework files to declare my resources to deploy.

In my `ROOT` API, I declare a series of outputs that my child lambdas depend on so that all my endpoints can have the same Rest API ID. This output declaration is nested under my `resources` declaration in my `serverless.yml` file as such:

```
resources:

  Resources:
    ...
    stuff here that you may need
    ...

  # API Gateway Cross Stack Reference Exports!!!!!
  # Outputs that other services will depend on!!!
  Outputs:
    ApiGatewayRestApiId:
      Value:
        Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
      Export:
        Name: ${self:custom.stage}-ApiGatewayRestApiId

    ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId:
      Value:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - ApiGatewayRestApi
          - RootResourceId
      Export:
        Name: ${self:custom.stage}-ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId
```

Once you have this implemented you then need to import the reference to this parent API resource in your child lambdas within the `provider` section of your `serverless.yml` file.

```
  # Cross-Stack Reference for sharing of API Gateway URI
  # created with accounting-api
  apiGateway:
    restApiId: ${cf:ROOT_API_NAME_HERE-dev.ApiGatewayRestApiId}
    #"Fn::ImportValue": ${self:custom.stage}-ApiGatewayRestApiId
    restApiRootResourceId:
      ${cf:ROOT_API_NAME_HERE-dev.ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId}
      #"Fn::ImportValue": ${self:custom.stage}-ApiGatewayRestApiRootResourceId
```

You must pay attention to the `restApiId` that you need to import from the `CloudFormation` stack from your parent API. You can review the outputs by going into the CloudFormation stack in your Parent API; click on Outputs and find your `restApiId` values as needed.

There is also another way that allows you to import the values using `Fn::ImportValue` which you can review with the example shown here:

https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-node-shared-gateway/users/serverless.yml

I have this method commented out in the code Ive pasted for you above for your reference.